# I am getting value error on find in mid

Tags: microsoft-excel, if

I am having Value error with this formula

- $H$5  cell value:  78th

when the cell value is:  78rd
formula drops correct value but when cell value is 78th it drops Value error.

```
=IF(MID($H$5;FIND("rd";$H$5);2)="rd";LEFT($H$5;FIND("rd";$H$5;1)-1);
 IF(MID($H$5;FIND("th";$H$5);2)="th";LEFT($H$5;FIND("th";$H$5;1)-1)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is coming from the first IFs logic.

You can wrap this in IFERROR, and repeat the second part:

```
=IF(IFERROR(MID($H$5,FIND("rd",$H$5),2),IF(MID($H$5,FIND("th",$H$5),2)="th",LEFT($H$5,FIND("th",$H$5,1)-1),"Value if false"))="rd",LEFT($H$5,FIND("rd",$H$5,1)-1), IF(MID($H$5,FIND("th",$H$5),2)="th",LEFT($H$5,FIND("th",$H$5,1)-1),"Value if false"))
```

This will only work for `TH` and `RD`

Comment: working, awesome, thanks a lot

Comment: @zgboi no probs, and welcome to Super User